# How to use a MVC action for downloading Google Drive streams

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api

I am trying to make a download link for Google Drive documents through my MVC Google Drive API application using the DownloadFile method suggested by Google Drive documentation:

```
public static System.IO.Stream DownloadFile(
  IAuthenticator authenticator, File file) {
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file.DownloadUrl)) {
  try {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
        new Uri(file.DownloadUrl));
    authenticator.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
      return response.GetResponseStream();
    } else {
      Console.WriteLine(
          "An error occurred: " + response.StatusDescription);
      return null;
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
    return null;
  }
} else {
  // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
  return null;
}
```

}

In the View I build the controller call by the following line:

```
<a href="#" id="btnDownloadResource" onclick="window.location.href='/LMS/Course/DownloadFile?downloadUrl=@resource.DownloadUrl&mimeType=@resource.MimeType&fileName=@resource.Title'">Download</a>
```

which correctly sends data to my controller's action:

```
public FileStreamResult DownloadFile(string downloadUrl, string mimeType, string fileName){
     System.IO.Stream stream = new GDriveRepository(Utils.ReturnIAuth((GoogleAuthenticator)Session["Gauthenticator"])).DownloadFile(downloadUrl);

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, mimeType);
}
```

But the download fails and I cannot figure out where I am wrong!

Comment: error message? http request/response?

Comment: Error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2s2GQjSbRb2OG80ZGgyVWFhOE0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That's the Google account chooser web page. It would be helpful to see the http request you're sending

Comment: Request/Response: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2s2GQjSbRb2S2VKTnZmTFV5Z1k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @pinoyyid is there any reference how to use the returning stream from google API method DownloadFile?

Comment: I don't use the SDK, sorry. Life is much easier using the http rest APIs

Comment: OK, in terms of REST how can I make DownloadFile requests in Drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not had to seek the file cause I was just trying to download the file. What I did is just read the stream i.e. through the DownloadFile API method and pass it to the browser. I enabled it through the following code:

```
public FileResult DownloadFile(string fileId)
    {
        DriveService service = Session["service"] as DriveService;
        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = service.Files.Get(fileId).Fetch(); 
        System.IO.Stream data = new GDriveRepository(Utils.ReturnIAuth((GoogleAuthenticator)Session["Gauthenticator"])).DownloadFile(file.DownloadUrl);

        return File(data, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, file.Title);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The request to download the file must include authorization information, specifically your OAuth2 access token. See the [Download Files guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads#examples) in the developer documentation for more information and sample code.

Comment: As you see I am doing it through the following line: System.IO.Stream stream = new GDriveRepository(Utils.ReturnIAuth((GoogleAuthenticator)Session["Gauthenticator"])).DownloadFile(downloadUrl);